# in EXtjs5.0.1, refresh can be used in grid, but this event can't be found in api, why?

Tags: grid, refresh, extjs5

I have used refresh event in Ext.grid.Panel of my application, and it works normally. While i can't find it in Extjs5.0.1 api document, why?

Answer (score 0):

`refresh` event is fired by [grid.View](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-event-refresh) in fact so, strictly speaking, you should not install listener on grid.Panel. Apparently it is propagated from the view to the panel, only it is not documented.